# Warning: [history] pushState is deprecated; use push instead

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, react-router

when using a  webpack + react + react-router + es6

**Warning: [history] pushState is deprecated; use push instead**

```
<pre>
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createHistory} from 'history';
import App from './component/app';
import About from './component/about';
import Concat from './component/concat';
import List from './component/list';
import {Router, Route} from 'react-router';
const history = createHistory();
const router = (
    <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="about" component={About} />
            <Route path="concat" component={Concat} />
            <Route path="list/:id" component={List} />
            <Route path="*" component={About}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    router,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</pre>
```

Comment: What's the `history` module? Is it from a package, or your own code? Either way, I don't see any evidence that `pushState` is deprecated at all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue myself today, it's due to the new merge request to the History repo:

https://github.com/rackt/history/commit/a9db75ac71b645dbd512407d7876799b70cab11c

[TEMP FIX]
Update your package.json, change "history" to "1.13.1" in dependencies. Do a "npm install" afterwards to update.

[REAL FIX]
Wait until someone merges a fix into react-router.

Comment: Just to note, what you are seeing is a deprecation warning only. I see no reason why you would forgo the bugfixes to avoid seeing a warning in the console.

Answer (score 2):

In previous versions of History (npm install history) pushState was used. pushState is a feature of HTML5 concerning the updating of the URL without navigating to a page/template/component.

This was deprecated in honor of push('path'), which is a cleaner better syntax according to some.

Replace

```
this.history.pushState(null, "/route/")
```

with

```
this.history.push('/store/' + storeId);
```

Comment: But `push` does not allow the passing of a `state` object? So how do we accomplish that?

Comment: Per docs here https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/master/docs/QuerySupport.md you  can provide a 'query' object that will map.  eg: history.push({ pathname: '/the/path', query: { the: 'query' } })

Answer (score 1):

**No**, the native browser history API **is not deprecated** and the `pushState` method is also **not deprecated** as of 2018 September. See the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API
https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/browsers.html#history
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#history

I'm starting to get the impression that the React community is a source of misinformation as it reinvents browser features because a library named `history` replaced its own pushState with a push method.

In my limited experience `history.pushState(<state-object>, 'page title', '#url')` works very well and the events from this API are reliable. It is highly useful to have `history.state` update (history's state, which can be linked to the document/global state as-desired) based on the location URL and history activity. Feel free to add corrections or insight via either edits or comments. This API is useful to understand and this question suggests there is a notion in the wild tending toward avoiding understanding native Web APIs--something I consider a strong antipattern counter to progress on the Web.